# how to perform arithmetic operation on 2D array returned through ResultSet in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a method in java that gives a table which has various columns.One of the columns is beam_current having values of real type till 220.**`Now I want to display only those rows of the table where beam_current values are closest to 10,20,30..till 220.`**

In order to do this I have to take a variable and assign it value 10 and subtract it with beam_current value and the least/smallest value I got should be in displayed in table.Have to run a for loop in while(rs.next) such as

```
while(rs.next)
{
  for(f=10;f<=220;f+10)`**//f+10 how to do in for?**`
 {
   variable=rs.getInt(2)`**//beam_current is second column**`
   f-=variable;
    code for least value of f`**//(how to code for it???)**`

 }
}
```

But I'm not getting how to code for this inner loop of while to retrieve the desired output.

My code for retrieving the table is

```js
public String[][] ref_Details() {

  int i = 0;
  String a[][] = new String[47][11];
  try {
    con = getConnection();
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    String sql = " select b.LOGTIME, b.beam_current, b.beam_energy,case when a.st1_vs1_bag1_onoff=0 then c.st1_vs1_bag1_rb ELSE 0 END as st1_vs1_bag1_rb ,CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag2_onoff=0  then c.st1_vs1_bag2_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag2_rb ,CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag3_onoff=0  then c.st1_vs1_bag3_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag3_rb ,CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag4_onoff=0  then c.st1_vs1_bag4_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag4_rb ,CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag5_onoff=0  then c.st1_vs1_bag5_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag5_rb ,CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag6_onoff=0  then c.st1_vs1_bag6_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag6_rb , CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag7_onoff=0  then c.st1_vs1_bag7_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag7_rb ,CASE when a.st1_vs1_bag8_onoff=0  then c.st1_vs1_bag8_rb else '0' END as st1_vs1_bag8_rb from INDUS2_BDS.dbo.DCCT b  INNER JOIN (main_vacuum_analog c inner join main_vacuum_status a on c.logtime=a.logtime) ON a.LOGTIME = b.LOGTIME and (  b.beam_current like '%9.97' or  b.beam_current like '%9.98' or  b.beam_current like '%9.99'  or  b.beam_current like '%0' or b.beam_current like '%0.01' or  b.beam_current like '%0.02' or  b.beam_current like '%0.03' or  b.beam_current like '%0.04' or  b.beam_current like '%0.05' or  b.beam_current like '%0.06')and b.logtime between '2014-10-10 07:17:00' and '2014-10-10 08:46:00'";
    stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    rs = stmt.getResultSet();

    while (rs.next())
    {
         for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
         a[i][j] = rs.getString(j + 1);


      }

      i++;
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("\nException " + e);
  } finally {
    closeConnection(stmt, rs, con);
  }
  return a;

}
```

Now I want to display only those rows which are closest to 10,20,30..till 220.

Comment: I assume the loop should be `for(f=10;f<=220;f+=10)`.  If you left out the last `=`, that's one problem that needs fixing.  But why are you modifying `f` inside that loop?  If you do that, the loop won't be executed for 10, 20, 30, ..., 220, because you have changed `f`.  And then next time through the loop, it adds 10 to the **changed** `f`.  I doubt this is what you want, even though I'm having trouble understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ajb I'm not getting how to move ahead with my problem.I just want those rows which are very near to values 10,20,,,upto 220.